# parent div does not grow in height

Tags: css, html, height, parent, children

I'm having trouble getting a parent div to extend its height as its children grow (Freud? :-))

[sample page here](http://nimya.50webs.com/green-label/test_1.html)

the parent here being "main_bottom" which contains "main_mid" and its children.

the structure is a little unusual because the text has to be **within** the rounded corners, which are large, so  i could not use the usual 'fixed top - then dynamic mid  -then  fixed bottom' routine.

of course the horrible pink and red are only so that the children divs  dimensions are easy to see..

any help will be highly appreciated

have a nice day

Comment: Link points to parked domain. Spam?

Comment: no spam, sorry - the linked worked ok until a few minutes ago. i'm looking into  it.. sorry again.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

One of the parent containers for the text has a fixed height, and the text is floated but not cleared. Remove the `height: 135px` (perhaps replace with `min-height`) rule from `#main_bottom` and add an `overflow: auto` rule to `#main_mid` to clear the float and the layout will work as intended.

Comment: Not at all the same problem I encountered, but similar enough that your reminder for overflow fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

add these definitions

```
#main_bottom {
  min-height: 600px;
  overflow: auto;
}


#main_mid {
  overflow: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

with `overflow: auto` and `height: auto` the container will fit to the content inside.

Comment: thanx :-)
note that using your solution created a scroll bar, which did not appear when a used the solution suggested by Reinis (bellow).
perhaps i could have gotten rid of it somehow in any case..
thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I met these problems couple time. My solution is that adding display:block; in child div and height:auto; in parent div.

```
div.parent {
    ...
    height: auto;
    ...
}
div.child {
    ...
    display: block;
    ...
}
```